# Is pointer good or is it the same as reference variable?

Tags: c++

Recently, I've learned about Pointers and so far, it seems like a glorified version of reference variable, is there any good uses for pointers that help make a code more efficient or something of that sort?

Comment: A pointer is not a glorified reference.  There are good uses for pointers.  I recommend looking at code that use pointers.

Comment: I believe the pointers were first, then came references :) Also, see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-vs-references-cpp/

Comment: It's the other way around. References are essentially pointers with some features removed.

Comment: A pointer is its own type.  A reference is the type, and may be optimized away in a surprisingly high number of cases.  A reference is more like an *alias* name for the same object.  And now with rvalue references and move semantics, us C++ developers have even finer grained control and can match the performance of FORTRAN on FORTRAN's home turf (which previously had very much annoyed me... thank you Howard Hinnant!).

Answer (score 3):

Both are "good", although in 2022, raw pointers in C++ are less useful than they once were. I go days without using them.

You are correct that `T&` and `T*` are similar. In particular, given `T& fooRef` and `T* const fooPtr` (where `T* const` is a pointer that cannot be changed) make it so that `fooRef` and `*fooPtr` are essentially the same. References can't be `nullptr` and cant be re-pointed. Pointers can be `nullptr` and can be `re-pointed`.

As @Macmade points out, pointers can point to the beginning of a contiguous buffer of many elements.

If you are new to C++, I'd recommend against using raw pointers. Almost everything can be done more safely with managed pointers, particularly `std::unique_ptr<T>`, which owns the thing it points to.

Comment: And may point to a series of values instead of a single one, may have multiple dimensions, etc… Probably worth mentioning…